# how does raspistill/raspivid display video without GUI?

Tags: opencv, raspivid

I'm trying to capture video from raspberry pi camera using OpenCV and display it without using gtk or x11. I noticed that **raspivid** displays camera output without using any window, I wonder if it's possible to use the same method to make opencv display video without using gtk.

**Edit**: I'm using raspbian lite without any desktop environment or GUI services, it's just a tty environment. I don't want to use any of their lightweight counterparts. How can I create a frame to display a picture/video on a tty environment and also use that approach to make OpenCV use it instead of regular windows generated by **namedWindow()** function?

Comment: Now the question is clear, but it seems that what you ask for requires some serious coding, and I wouldn't expect people to write code for you.

Comment: So the [linux framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) is one way to do this; it is accessed via a special device node and [an `iotctl()` based C API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/api.html).  However, glancing at [the raspicam/raspivid source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/0858c4bd1708d4e2dcb1f63727a99f2fa1d4d5a7/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam) I think it uses the VideoCore libraries distributed with the pi: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmal

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for your great explanations! A lot of helpful info in 4 lines. Actually the way raspistill uses VideoCore libraries might help me to get to the answer. Instead of creating a window using OpenCV I might be able to feed image data to the mmal component, preview, in order to display image. I will dig in more, you might want to write the answer so that I can approve it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of  playing video on command line you can use scp and download recorded video from raspberry pi to your system then you can enjoy your video.

Comment: What is sap protocol? The question you answered wasn't asked.

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2016/11/07/download-file-from-server-scp-ssh/

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I posted this. The answer you gave is not particularly the answer to my question, I'm aware of SSH protocol and I know how to use it but what I want is not to watch a video in any possible way, but in a particular way which is through a TTY. As you might guessed, TTY is an environment where user interface does not exist. So the question is: how can a video, which is inherently visual and only available through user interfaces, can be played on a TTY?